# Is it safe to explicitly cast type in the switch statement where case is type I cast to?

Tags: swift

I have this code, I wonder if it is safe to use `as!` here.

```
switch value {
    case is [String]:
        setCustomAttributeArrayWithKey(key, array: value as! [String])
    default:
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It it safe in your particular case, but error-prone: What if
you reuse that code and change only one occurrence of `[String]`
but forget to change the other occurrence? Generally, a forced cast
with `as!` should be avoided whenever possible.

And it *is* possible here, using a pattern binding:

```
switch value {
    case let stringArray as [String]:
        setCustomAttributeArrayWithKey(key, array: stringArray)
    default:
        ...
}
```

does the same in a less error-prone way: No repetition of the
`[String]` type and no forced cast with `as!`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its safe since the switch binding has already established that its a non-optional String array and has a valid value. This is assuming that value can be of any type at run time.